# Eclipse - Clojure - Counterclockwise plugin - shortcut for evaluating selection in REPL namespace (not file namespace)

Tags: eclipse, clojure, shortcut, read-eval-print-loop, counterclockwise

Suppose I have my first file/namespace with the following:

```
(ns a)
```

I run this to get a repl with 'Clojure/Load File in REPL'

Then I open up a second file/namespace with the following:

```
(ns b)

(ns c)

(println *ns*)
```

Suppose I select the `(ns b)` and hit Command-Enter (on my mac - on windows it would be CTRL-enter). Then I select the `(ns c)` and hit Command-Enter.

Then I select the `(println *ns*)` and hit command-enter - then I get:

```
#<Namespace b>
```

Because the shortcut Command-Enter evaluates the hilighted text not in the repl namespace but the file namespace.

Is there a shortcut to evaluate the selection in the repl namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [no](https://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/wiki/EditorKeyBindingsFeatures#Interaction_with_the_REPL), not directly. However, there is a shortcut to switch the repl to the namespace of the current file and then you could execute the code.